# ERROR in Error: channel closed at ChildProcess.target.send (internal/child_process.js:562:16)

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, angular5

I am getting this error message, after running my Angular 5 application.

> ERROR in Error: channel closed
>       at ChildProcess.target.send (internal/child_process.js:562:16)
>       at AngularCompilerPlugin._updateForkedTypeChecker (D:\SVenu\FullStackDevelopment\Angular\Angular5\ng5\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:370:34)
>       at Promise.resolve.then (D:\SVenu\FullStackDevelopment\Angular\Angular5\ng5\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:208:22)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)

It works fine for few minutes after I run `ng serve`. Anyone have faced this same issue? Below is my `package.json` file.

```
{
  "name": "ng5",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.5",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

I had already gone through some related question, but none of the solutions provided helped me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

change @angular/cli version to 1.5.2 or downgrade to 1.4.0.